# File I/O isolating a word in a text file

Tags: python, file, input, output

I am currently working on a file reading assignment using python 2.7.5.  Our first task is to read in the two file provided to us (one is a story and the other is a dictionary).  There is one word per line in the dictionary file.  Then, check every word in the story file to see if it is in the dictionary.  If it is, we print the word.  Here is my code:

```
story = set(open("story.txt").read().strip().split("\n"))
dictionary = open("dictionary.txt").read().strip().split("\n")

for word in story:
    word = word.strip(',():;.')
    if word not in dictionary:
        print(word)
```

I am currently having problems getting each individual word in the story as this program is outputting various LINES from the story file.  I would appreciate some help with finding each individual word in the story.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading the story, just use `split()`, instead of `split('\n')`:

```
In [1]: '''This is a text.
   ...: There is also a second line.'''.split()
Out[1]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'text.', 'There', 'is', 'also', 'a', 'second', 'line.']
```

The first call splits on all whitespace, the second only on newlines.

Before splitting the text, it would be best to remove punctuation;

```
with open('story.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
data = data.translate(None, ';:.,!?')
words = data.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

The programming is outputting lines of the story because you are splitting the text into a list of lines when you say `.split("\n")` . Why are you doing that? Also, think about what happens when you have words at the beginning of a sentence.